# How to run a Ruby script in interactive mode

Tags: ruby

In MATLAB, if one writes a script and runs it, the variables defined in the script are available at the command line prompt. I would like to do something similar with IRB or Pry. I wrote a script called "scratch.rb" which simply reads

```
x = 0
```

If I type "irb" in the command line in the same directory as this script and type

```
> load 'scratch.rb'
```

This appears to run the Ruby script (as I've confirmed by adding a p command). However, if immediately thereafter I try to 'echo' the variable x by

```
> x
```

I get an error

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object
```

Is it possible to make the variables available interactively in this way?

Comment: it'll work if you do `@x = 0` and referencing it as `@x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not. Local variables are scoped within the file.

If you want to bruce force, you can read the file as a string and eval it in the binding of the root environment of irb.